How to maintain line breaks for the pasted text in TipTap editor?
Even a TipTap editor playground does that - when you paste a text with line breaks, it will remove line breaks and will display text without them.
How can I make editor to retain the line breaks when pasting a text?
Edit: this is how it's done
const editor = {
  editorProps: {
    handlePaste: (view, event, slice) => {
      // Prevent the default paste behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get plain text from clipboard
      const text = event.clipboardData?.getData("text/plain");

      if (text) {
        // Split text by newlines
        const lines = text.split(/\n/);

        // Insert each line with proper paragraph formatting
        const tr = view.state.tr;
        lines.forEach((line, index) => {
          // Insert line
          tr.insertText(line);

          // Add newline between paragraphs (except for last line)
          if (index < lines.length - 1) {
            tr.split(tr.selection.from);
          }
        });

        view.dispatch(tr);
      }

      return true;
    },
  },
}


Did you solve this? Im just now facing this issue.

@Nex I've solved it, and gave you the solution in the post edit.
